# Why would pandas groupby resampling be taking forever?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Pandas Verion: 1.5.3

Python Version: 3.9.13

I'm trying to resample a pandas dataframe of some time series data which is divided by id. I've seen a million examples of this online, and frankly, have used this technique myself many times. However, for some reason, I have a dataframe that is taking an extremely long time to resample my data, despite being a rather reasonable amount of rows (~250k).

The structure is very simple:

| item_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-01-05 | 5 |

I've oversimplified, but this is the core idea. What I want to do is resample this, grouped by `item_id`, with a frequency of 'per day'. The resulting table should look like this after resampling...

| item_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-01-02 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-03 | 3 |
| 1 | 2023-01-04 | NaN |
| 1 | 2023-01-05 | 5 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-01-02 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-01-03 | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-01-04 | NaN |
| 2 | 2023-01-05 | 5 |

Keep in mind, I'm looking for the resampling `min`/`max` to be within each `item_id` group, so for the sake of this question, I'm not looking for the `stack`/`unstack` method (however, that method does execute almost instantly on this dataset).

Assuming `df` is my dataframe before sampling, this would be the python code I would use...

```
# First clean types / set index
df = df.astype({
    'item_id': 'str',
    'value': 'int'
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.set_index('date')

# Resample
df = df.groupby('item_id').resample('D').value.mean()
```

If I run this code on ~250k rows, it takes approximately 12min to execute. That's so long I MUST assume that I'm doing something wrong here... but for the life of me I cannot see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many groups do you have? And what is your real code (for min/max)? If you resample by 'D', do you have a time part or just missing days? => In fact can you provide a sample of your real data because your code have no problem.

Comment: @Corralien I have 63633 groups. What you see is my real code, if you do this resampling technique it automatically resamples within the min/max of each group. And I just have missing days.

Comment: Ok so the important part of your problem is you have 63633 which is huge for only 250K rows. 1 group for only 4 rows.

Comment: Hmm.. I honestly didn't consider that as being that big of an issue... Here's the weird thing though, yesterday I did this exact same thing on the same dataset, same number of ids, but with more time series data (~86 million rows) and that took a similar amount of time...?

Comment: 86M rows for how many groups? Groupby/Resampling for few groups is fast but for many groups, it can be very long... (like a for loop). Maybe you can use multiprocessing?

Comment: I created a DataFrame with 254528 rows and 63633... I have the same problem :-)

Comment: Same number of groups. It was the exact same, just more timepoints were included. Which is why I'm so confused.. I might just end up using the stack/unstack method and deal with the padding somehow because that executes instantly

Comment: Oh wow, ok then I'll definitely just use the stack/unstack method in that case and take the hint. Thank you so much for verifying that <3

Comment: Just in case anyone else finds this, I also discovered that grouping by an `int64` column was quite a bit faster.